# How and where to modify Magento search query?

Tags: magento, collections, e-commerce, entity-attribute-value, magento-1.6

First of all, I found similar questions in SO but there is not any answer for them. So, the first part of the question is a little bit duplicated. I want to improve search results in Magento. Here is what I've done already:

**1.** Search with `AND` instead of `OR` when there are multiple words.

**2.** Ajax search starts searching from anywhere and not only from the beginning of the fields.

**3.** Trim the last `s` from the words to prevent empty results when searching with plurals.

**4.** I changed the search type from `Like` to `Fulltext` or `Combine` but the results were not better and even were worst, so I leave it as is. It's `Like` now, so there is no `relevance` ordering.

The last thing which I want to try is [adding this to the search query](http://www.rocketweb.com/blog/improving-magento-search):

```
SELECT ... other non-full-text-cols
MATCH (product_title) AGAINST ('lean body for her') AS rel1,
MATCH (content) AGAINST ('lean body for her') AS rel2
FROM table
WHERE MATCH (product_title,content) AGAINST ('lean body for her')
ORDER BY (rel1*1.5)+(rel2)
```

Here is my query but I'm not sure if it would work because I can't test it:

```
$this->_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect(
    array(
    'rel1' => new Zend_Db_Expr('MATCH (name) AGAINST ("'.$queryText.'")'),
    'rel2' => new Zend_Db_Expr('MATCH (short_description) AGAINST ("'.$queryText.'")')
    )
);

$this->_productCollection->getSelect()
    ->where('MATCH (name,short_description) AGAINST ("'.$queryText.'")')
    ->order('(rel1*1.5)+(rel2)');
```

The main idea is to add bonus weight to a result if the search query is found in the title of the product. The problem is that I don't know where to modify the query. I can't find where it is at all. `$this->_productCollection` is not the right object, I know it. I looked at all the `Collection.php` files, resource models, models and even the query log but no luck. There are just little 1 or 2 row parts in some files but not a full query. I'm new to Magento and still have problems with finding this type of stuff. So, where I have to place my additional stuff when I have to extend a query?

Community Edition Magento, version 1.6.1.0.

Note: I know that some extension for improving search results will work much better than my solutions but for now I have to do it in that way. It would be a good experience for me, too.

**Edit:**

So, I figured out how to add my custom fields for the ordering but it's
untruly I think. In `class Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer`'s `prepareProductCollection` method I added two joins to the query and get the fields `rel1` and `rel2`:

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('cpev' => 'catalog_product_entity_varchar'),
    'cpev.entity_id = e.entity_id AND cpev.attribute_id = 96',
    array('rel1' => new Zend_Db_Expr('2.01*(LENGTH(cpev.value) - LENGTH(REPLACE(LCASE(cpev.value), LCASE("'.$queryText.'"), ""))) / LENGTH("'.$queryText.'")'))
);

$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('cpet' => 'catalog_product_entity_text'),
    'cpet.entity_id = e.entity_id AND cpet.attribute_id = 506',
    array('rel2' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(LENGTH(cpet.value) - LENGTH(REPLACE(LCASE(cpet.value), LCASE("'.$queryText.'"), ""))) / LENGTH("'.$queryText.'")'))
);
```

I have these fields now but as you can see I have hard coded stuff like `attribute_id = 96` etc. which is not good at all and it will not work everytime - I checked these ids directly from the database tables. I wrote it like this because I haven't access to `name` and `short_description` fields but they are in the result. Don't know why. So, `cpev.value` is `name` field and `cpet.value` is the `short_description` field. Moreover I can't order the results by these fields. I tried `$collection->addOrder('SUM(rel1+rel2)');`, `$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(rel1+rel2)').' DESC');`, some `addAttributeToFilter` stuff etc. but it's not working.

**Edit 2:**
I accepted *@james*' answer but finally we bought an extension for improving the search results.

Comment: Using Solr or ElasticSearch I believe it's a better approach to your issue. It's a better fit to cover plural/singular search, synonyms, spelling, relevance.

Comment: Thanks, @FlorinelChis. I checked different Magento extensions, too. But for now I want doing it in that way because I'm not very experienced for adding 3rd party stuff and the second thing is that I haven't much rights on the web shop. Could you help for modifying the original query, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext` check out `prepareResult` (line 310 in 1.7 CE) and look for the following:

```
$select->columns(array('relevance'  => new Zend_Db_Expr(0)));
```

Magento sets all search result relevances as 0 (!); add the relevances you want (higher is better) here. You can create a custom query in `Zend_Db_Expr()` to generate higher relevances on attribute matches.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your first question (1): 
To make an AND search instead of OR, you will need to rewrite the class

```
Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext
```

In the method

```
public function prepareResult($object, $queryText, $query)
```

you want to switch the part

```
$likeCond = '(' . join(' OR ', $like) . ')';
```

to

```
$likeCond = '(' . join(' AND ', $like) . ')';
```

Be sure to reindex the search index afterwards to have an effect.

Comment: _Here is what I've done already:_ was at the head of the list

Comment: @mpaepper, I already done these. My problem is modifying the search query.