# Popular Search Terms in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I am new to magento. i am have one problem , i have to modify search terms insert query. but i am not able to find it in magento. i am using magento 1.8 version. so if any one have any idea please share. one more thing, if i have to add more field in search query. where and which file i have to modify. please mention the path for files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947976/how-and-where-to-modify-magento-search-query

Comment: thanks, but i have to modify search term insert query in magento but i am not getting how and where i can find the actual insert query for that. so please if you have any idea about it please share

Comment: That find in app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Model\Resource\Fulltext.php in that function prepareResult($object, $queryText, $query). first truncate table `catalogsearch_fulltext`,`catalogsearch_query`, `catalogsearch_result` .

Answer (score 1):

In this file remove save code and update your query.

/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/ResultController.php